# how do I view sessions as the main graph here (see photo)

Tags: google-analytics

Under Acquisition --> Overview, a graph appears around middle of the screen titled "sessions". It is actually showing the total number of users over a particular time period, I'd like it to show the number of sessions and not users on the blue graph.

Before it showed the number of sessions but changed, now it shows users. I want it back to sessions.

How do I change it?[image: analytics image]